# Please explain what's going on in this part of the C# code using line => line and .toArray

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Here's the code:

```
File.ReadLines(sourceFilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();
```

I get what's going on up until the "Select" keyword.  Can someone please break down what is going on in "line => line.Split...

My understanding is that we are going line by line through the text file and parsing and splitting a line of input text by tabs (since I know the text is tab-delimited).  But, what exactly is going on with "line => line..."?

And I get at the end of the line of code the text is going into an Array.  But when I debug and step through the code and use the locals window what is the name of the Array that contains what has been read?  How do I see what is read into the Array?

Comment: First: is this code working? I mean, is it doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: That's called a Lambda Expression.

Comment: Second: **it's a lambda expression**. It could be read like: `line` *goes to* `[expression]`, where `line` is each element of the previous collection.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses everyone.  The explanations have been helpful as well as calling my attention to "Lambda expressions" and having me google it.  Last question,  in VB I am used to creating an array and populating it and then looking at it in the locals window to see what the array contains.  How do I do that for this array?  What is the array even called in this C# code?  Thanks.

Comment: @phan do not ask additional questions in your comments.  If the additional info is related to your original question, update your post and add that information in.  Otherwise, please ask a separate question.

Comment: MikeC.  I asked this question in the original question (read 3rd paragraph), and I am now trying to call attention to it since no one had answered that part of the question.

Comment: @phan assign the result to a variable `var arr = File.ReadLines(.....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is saying, essentially, "For each line in the file, split the line on the tab character into an array of strings, then create an array of those arrays (such that each element in the returned array is an array)"

The `Select` function takes an Enumerable of something and applies a function to each item, producing 1 output value for each input value.  In other programming languages this is called a Map or a Projection.

The => indicates a lambda expression which is compiled into a delegate function.  It takes an argument called "line", whose type is inferred by the usage (because `ReadLines` returns an IEnumerable of Strings, `line` is of type String).

The lambda's body has an implied return type of the value resulting from the last call (the call to `Split`).  Thus, the line says "run this lambda on each line".

Finally, the call to `.ToArray` at the end (outside of the lambda) converts the `IEnumerable<String[]>` returned by `Select` into an array of arrays (`String[][]`).

Answer (score 3):

The `=>` is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - think of it as a type of [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171) or as an [Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151).  Each item that is returned from `File.Readlines` is operated on by the `Select` - the `Select` passes each line through the lambda function `line => line.Split('\t')` which takes a single argument (named `line`) and then returns the result of calling `.Split('\t')` on the `line` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` operator is a LINQ extension method used to handle projecting elements from a collection into a different form.  The most common usage would be to select a single column from the elements of that collection into a new collection, however more complex projections can be handled inside the lambda expression.

The compiler automatically infers the datatype returned by the `Select` method so that its dependent on whatever the output is of the lambda you pass in.  In your case, the output of the lambda is an Array of strings, so ultimately it returns an `IEnumerable<string[]>`.  When you call `ToArray()` at the end, you then convert the `IEnumerable<string[]>` into a concrete  `string[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is Linq.

The Select method is an extension on IEnumerable, it lets you 'project' each result into some other form using a lambda expression (the line => ... part)

In this case, the developer wants to split each line on the tab character (resulting in an array, this is the projection) and retrieve an array containing each result.